# Javascript Countdown application doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple counter, so that every request made to path \count would decrease the count by one. Once it's below 1, it will response with the message "Finished". Requests to any other path would get a response "None". Can someone tell me what to change?

```
let count = 5;
const handleRequest = (request) => {  
  const url = new URL(request.url);
 
  let message = "Finished";   
  if (url.pathname === "/count" && count >=1) {


count--;
    return new Response(count); 
     
  } else if (url.pathname ==="/count" && count < 1); { 
    return new Response(message); 
  } else {
    return new Response("None") 
  } 
};
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon in line `} else if (url.pathname ==="/count" && count < 1); {`

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, it appears that you are returning a value before decrementing the count. This stops the decrementing line from running and therefore not affecting the count.

Try swapping the return statement and the decrement:

```
let count = 5;
...
if (url.pathname === "/count" && count >=1) { 
    count--; 
    return new Response(count); 
} else if (url.pathname ==="/count" && count < 1); { 
 ...
} 
};
```

Comment: I tried that, but still keep on getting the same error message and it refers to the second last line saying unexpected token "}". If I remove it, I just get one error more. I find it so hard to understand JavaScript errors.

Comment: Send the updated code so i can have a look along with the exact error messages you are getting.

Comment: @KJM what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I updated the original code I posted. Error message is : error: The module's source code could not be parsed: Unexpected token `else`. Expected this, import, async, function, [ for array literal, { for object literal, @ array literal, { for object literal, @ for decorator, function, class, null, true, false, number, bigint, string, regexp, fier at file:///C:/Users/XXX/XXX
` for template literal, (, or an identifier at file:///C:/Users/XXX/XXX/Ty%C3%B6p%C3%B6yt%C3%A4/WSD/counter.js:15:3     
PS C:\Users\XXX\XXX\XXX\Apps>

Comment: refer to @tjarbo 's comment on original post to fix the error

Comment: Thanks guys, small things which were difficult to spot!